# Hierarchical TreeView from DataSet

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview

I'm new in WPF and cant get how to bind that dataset to treeview

```
Dim dtHDD As New DataTable("Disks")
dtHDD.Columns.Add("ID")
dtHDD.Columns.Add("DiskName")

dtHDD.Rows.Add(1, "Disc1")
dtHDD.Rows.Add(2, "Disc2")

Dim dtFolders As New DataTable("Folders")
dtFolders.Columns.Add("ID")
dtFolders.Columns.Add("DiskID")
dtFolders.Columns.Add("FolderID")
dtFolders.Columns.Add("FolderName")

dtFolders.Rows.Add(1, 2, DBNull.Value, "Music")
dtFolders.Rows.Add(2, 1, DBNull.Value, "Documents")
dtFolders.Rows.Add(3, 1, 2, "Scatches")
dtFolders.Rows.Add(4, 1, 3, "Images")
dtFolders.Rows.Add(5, 1, 3, "Folder1")
dtFolders.Rows.Add(6, 1, 2, "Bin")
dtFolders.Rows.Add(7, 2, DBNull.Value, "Moves")
dtFolders.Rows.Add(8, 1, 5, "Another one")


Dim dtFiles As New DataTable("Files")
dtFiles.Columns.Add("ID")
dtFiles.Columns.Add("FolderID")
dtFiles.Columns.Add("FileName")

dtFiles.Rows.Add(1, 8, "file1")
dtFiles.Rows.Add(2, 2, "file2")
dtFiles.Rows.Add(3, 3, "file3")
dtFiles.Rows.Add(4, 2, "file4")
dtFiles.Rows.Add(5, 5, "file5")
dtFiles.Rows.Add(6, 5, "file6")
dtFiles.Rows.Add(7, 8, "file7")
dtFiles.Rows.Add(8, 8, "file8")
dtFiles.Rows.Add(9, 1, "file9")

Dim ds As New DataSet
ds.Tables.Add(dtHDD)
ds.Tables.Add(dtFolders)
ds.Tables.Add(dtFiles)
ds.Relations.Add("DiskFolder", ds.Tables("Disks").Columns("ID"), ds.Tables("Folders").Columns("DiskID"))
ds.Relations.Add("FolderFolder", ds.Tables("Folders").Columns("ID"), ds.Tables("Folders").Columns("FolderID"))
ds.Relations.Add("FolderFile", ds.Tables("Folders").Columns("ID"), ds.Tables("Files").Columns("FolderID"))

treeTest.ItemsSource = ds.Tables("Disks").DefaultView
```

So each disk can contain folders only.
Each folder can contain files and folders.
I made the following markup

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeTest" Margin="380,0,0,0">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding DiskFolder}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DiskName}"/>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FolderName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

But I don't know how to set RowFilter rule for Folder table and how add files in that treeview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a DataTemplateSelector that selects the appropriate template based on the name of the parent table:

```
Public Class TemplateSelector
    Inherits DataTemplateSelector

    Public Property DiskTemplate As DataTemplate
    Public Property FolderTemplate As DataTemplate
    Public Property FileTemplate As DataTemplate

    Public Overrides Function SelectTemplate(item As Object, container As DependencyObject) As DataTemplate

        Dim drv = CType(item, System.Data.DataRowView)
        Select Case drv.DataView.Table.TableName
            Case "Disks"
                Return DiskTemplate
            Case "Folders"
                Return FolderTemplate
            Case "Files"
                Return FileTemplate
        End Select

        Return Nothing

    End Function

End Class
```

Usage:

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="diskTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding DiskFolder}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DiskName}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="folderTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding FolderFile}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FolderName}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="fileTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <local:TemplateSelector x:Key="TemplateSelector"
                                DiskTemplate="{StaticResource diskTemplate}" 
                                FolderTemplate="{StaticResource folderTemplate}"
                                FileTemplate="{StaticResource fileTemplate}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TreeView x:Name="treeTest" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! It's almost what I need. In this example, the relation "FolderFolder" does not work
"Itages" folder should be in the "Scatches" folder and the "Scatches" folder should be in the "Documents". Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have done that way

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="folderTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding FolderFolder}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FolderName}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

[MyWindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBw2d.png)

I think the left to add a filter for the rows

```
RowFilter = "FolderID is null"
```

But how don't get it...

Comment: Which nodes do you want to hide?

Comment: High level nodes with "FolderID" is null

Comment: "High level" nodes? *Which* nodes?

Comment: "Disc1" must have just one folder "Documents"

Answer (score 0):

Finally i want see that structure

```
<disc Name="Disc1">
    <folder Name="Documents">
        <folder Name="Scatches">
            <folder Name="Images"/>
            <folder Name="Folder1">
                <folder Name="Another one">
                    <file Name="file1"/>
                    <file Name="file7"/>
                    <file Name="file8"/>
                </folder>
                <file Name="file5"/>
                <file Name="file6"/>
            </folder>
            <file Name="file3"/>
        </folder>
        <folder Name="Bin"/>
        <file Name="file2"/>
        <file Name="file4"/>
    </folder>
</disc>
<disc Name="Disc2">
    <folder Name="Music">
        <file Name="file9"/>
    </folder>
    <folder Name="Moves" />
</disc>
```